# How to show red border at Invalid Input Box after clicking Submit button with angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to make a form validation using angularjs. I could manage it anyway. Now, I'm trying to add a red border at input box when it's invalid. I can do this by adding this css:

```
/*Show red border if kept the input empty after touching*/
.ng-touched.ng-invalid-required {
    border-color: red;
}
/* Show red border when stuff has been typed in, but its invalid */
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
/*Show normal border color when typed in for the first time*/
.ng-untouched.ng-invalid {
    border-color: #ccc; 
}
```

But, at the first time if any input box is empty and untouched and at that time if anybody click 'Submit' button, it'll show error message but it don't show any red border:

[image]

I don't understand which class I should define in CSS for this scenario. How can I make the input box red bordered if anybody click the 'Submit' button keeping input box empty and untouched?

[Here is the plunker work](http://plnkr.co/edit/I7XkqDK64HGeFFjDB3uS?p=preview).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue--I opened the plunkr and clicked submit and I saw boxes with red borders--is this not what you want?

Comment: If you don't touch any input and click submit, the red border won't come. This is the issue

Comment: That's what I did, but I do see the border. I am using Chrome.

Comment: I am not sure why you're seeing that. But, I see the same result at every browser. I uploaded screenshot what I faced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nested class inside your css using `ng-submitted`

```
/*Show red border if kept the input empty after touching*/
.ng-touched.ng-invalid-required {
    border-color: red;
}
/* Show red border when stuff has been typed in, but its invalid */
.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
/*Show normal border color when typed in for the first time*/
.ng-untouched.ng-invalid {
    border-color: #ccc; 
}
.ng-submitted input.ng-invalid{
    border-color: red;
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/I7XkqDK64HGeFFjDB3uS?p=preview)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: The issue is still there (like the screenshot) on your Plunkr

Comment: @user1896653 you don't want that messages at when form is untouched and dirty? What should be the behaviour? What would be the starting validation, without filling any fields?

Comment: No, I want the messages. the issue is when form is submitted and untouched,  I want red border at the input filed. Currently, it's showing only the messages at this scenario(I have posted screenshot of that). With those messages I want input box would be red bordered too. Look, before clicking to the submit button, when input is dirty, it'll get red bordered with the messages. Only for submitted and untouched, it don't get red border but 'Required Messages'. With those 'Required Messages' I want red border at the input box too.

Comment: @user1896653 check my updated answer & plunkr..and let me know if anything is pending

Comment: Accept my editing and it'll end :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the last css declation to match :

```
.ng-pristine {
    border-color: red;  
}
```

EDIT :

To show a red border only after submitting you could use a [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) attribute with a condition on : createLogin.$submitted

Comment: I have edited it to change the color. Or have i misunderstand your issue ?

Comment: Issue is: input box should be red if anyone 'Don't Touch the Input Box' and 'Click the Submit Button'. Currently, only red message box is showing for this scenario(screenshot of the post), but I need red border-ed input box too for this scenario.