# How to show red border around the invalid fields in react semantic forms

Tags: forms, reactjs

```
<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} ref="Form">
   <Form.Input label="First Name" name="firstName" type='text' required />
</Form>
```

Currently, if firstName field is blank it shows a popup of html5 validation. But, I'd like to show red border around all the invalid fields.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove that required html5 attribute and check `onSubmit` function where there is any input or not.

And if you want to show red border just add a class in your text field.

```
<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} ref="Form">
   <Form.Input label="First Name" className={this.state.inputClass} name="firstName" type='text' required />
</Form>
```

and manage this className on your onSubmit() function by applying if condition

```
onSubmit(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 if(! whatever your condition is to check whether name is valid or not)
 this.setState({
  inputClass: "invalid"
 })
}
```

your invalid will be like

```
.invalid{
border:1px solid #ff0000
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But I had already thought of this.. Actually in my form there are many required fields.. In that case it would not be a good solution to check for all the fields

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482128/how-to-show-red-border-at-invalid-input-box-after-clicking-submit-button-with-an

Comment: Since I am using react and not angularjs, input won't have these classes

Comment: Then I think the standard way is to check whether field is empty or not and assign the class to those fields . What's the problem in that?

Comment: Not problem exactly..But its tedious, since there are many required fields. Also, onChange I'll have to again check if its valid or still invalid. And I am using another component inside my form where it might get bit complicated. Anyway, I'll do this only until I find a better solution. :)

Comment: Yes, Thats a bit of work to do. But is it necessary to make the input field border look red if its not valid?

Comment: This solution really worked for me.. In my case I set border color in style attribute dynamically as class was used in multiple fields.. Thanks.